# Certain areas suddenly became unclickable in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: error-handling, 23.04, troubleshooting

Some areas on the top right under the battery indicator (especially for close, maximize, minimize) suddenly became unclickable when opening any app, but when opening File Explorer the area returned to normal by itself and became clickable again.

Can anyone help me to find out what the problem is? And what is the solution?